# Root finding using a loop

Tags: scipy, root

I have one equation defined in the function

```
def fun(x, y, z, v, b):
       Y = (z*(np.sign(x) * (np.abs(x))**(y-1))) - (v*np.sign(b) * (np.abs(b))**(v-1))/(1-b**v)
       return Y.flatten()
```

that I want to solve for the value of x, given the values of Z0, SS (year 1: Z0=1.2, SS=2, ...) and different combinations of `alpha` and `kappa`, for which I am creating a grid.

```
Z0 = [1.2, 5, 3, 2.5, 4.2]
SS = [2, 3, 2.2, 3.5, 5]

ngrid = 10
kv = np.linspace(0.05, 2, ngrid)
av = np.linspace(1.5, 4, ngrid)

q0 = []                    
for z in range(len(Z0)):
    zz = Z0[z]
    ss = SS[z]
    for i in range(ngrid):
        for j in range(ngrid):
            kappa = kv[i]
            alpha = av[j]
            res0 = root(lambda x: fun(x, alpha, zz, kappa, ss), x0=np.ones(range(ngrid)))
            q0 = res0.x
            print(q0)
```

where y = alpha; v=kappa, z = Z0; b = S.

I am getting all [], [], ....

Not sure what is going on. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you attempt to use `res0.x`, check `res0.success`. In this case, you'll find that it is `False` in each case.  When `res0.success` is False, take a look at `res0.message` for information about why `root` failed.

During development and debugging, you might also consider getting the solver working for just one set of parameter values before you embed `root` in three nested loops.  For example, here are a few lines from an ipython session (variables were defined in previous lines, not shown):

```
In [37]: res0 = root(lambda x: fun(x, av[0], Z0[0], kv[0], SS[0]), x0=np.ones(range(ngrid)))

In [38]: res0.success
Out[38]: False

In [39]: res0.message
Out[39]: 'Improper input parameters were entered.'
```

The message suggests that something is wrong with the input parameters.  You call `root` like this:

```
        res0 = root(lambda x: fun(x, alpha, zz, kappa, ss), x0=np.ones(range(ngrid)))
```

A close look at that line shows the problem: the initial guess is `np.ones(range(ngrid))`:

```
In [41]: np.ones(range(ngrid))
Out[41]: array([], shape=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), dtype=float64)
```

That's not what you want!  The use of `range` looks like a simple typo (or "thinko").  The initial guess should be

```
x0=np.ones(ngrid)
```

In ipython, we get:

```
In [50]: res0 = root(lambda x: fun(x, av[0], Z0[0], kv[0], SS[0]), x0=np.ones(ngrid))

In [51]: res0.success
Out[51]: True

In [52]: res0.x
Out[52]: 
array([-0.37405428, -0.37405428, -0.37405428, -0.37405428, -0.37405428,
       -0.37405428, -0.37405428, -0.37405428, -0.37405428, -0.37405428])
```

All the return values are the same (and this happens for other parameters values), which suggests that you are solving a *scalar* equation.  A closer look at `fun` shows that you only use `x` in element-wise operations, so you are in fact solving just a scalar equation.  In that case, you can use `x0=1`:

```
In [65]: res0 = root(lambda x: fun(x, av[0], Z0[0], kv[0], SS[0]), x0=1)

In [66]: res0.success
Out[66]: True

In [67]: res0.x
Out[67]: array([-0.37405428])
```

You could also consider using `root_scalar` instead of `root`.